# NSStatusBar animating text

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to animated text in the NSStatusBar similar to how the text "Dialing ..." scroll from right to left when dialing-up to Internet.

I'm not sure how to do this so is there some code example or guide on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search threw this up.
[Animate Large Scrolling Text](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BestWayToAnimateLargeScrollingText)